# Check lists are equal whilst accounting for nulls

Tags: c#, list, null, equals

```
public bool Equals(Permissions that)
{
    if (Groups == null && that.Groups != null || Groups != null && that.Groups == null) return false;
    if (Users == null && that.Users != null || Users != null && that.Users == null) return false;

    if (Groups != null && Users != null)
        return Groups.SequenceEqual(that.Groups) && Users.SequenceEqual(that.Users);

    return Groups != null ? Groups.SequenceEqual(that.Groups) : Users.SequenceEqual(that.Users);
}
```

How can I check that both lists are equal whilst also accounting for null's in a better way than this?

Comment: Use the elvis-operator: `foo?.bar == baz?.qux`.

Comment: @Dai Will that help with enumerables (like here)?

Comment: @mjwills It simplifies the length-equality checks which are an optimization.

Comment: @Dai Show us _how_ to do that. Since, if it is `IEnumerable` there is no length (without enumeration - in which case you may as well do `SequenceEqual`) to speak of.

Comment: The code in your sample will throw an exception if `Users` is `null`, won't it?  (In the last line we call a method without checking for `null` when we do: `Users.SequenceEqual`

Comment: @mjwills I should clarify: if *both* `Users` and `that.Users` are `null` it will throw an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least you can extract collection comparison into separate method:

```
public static bool BothNullOrEquals<T>(IEnumerable<T> left, IEnumerable<T> right)
{
    if (left == null && right == null)
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (left != null && right != null)
    {
        return left.SequenceEqual(right);
    }
    return false;
}

public bool Equals(Permissions that)
{
     return BothNullOrEquals(Groups, that.Groups) && BothNullOrEquals(Users, that.Users);
}
```